# Does the order of add_action and function matter?

Tags: php, wordpress

In many instances, I see a function followed by the `add_action` command.

But in terms of the visual flow, I always move the `add_action` underneath the function, and it still works.

I would like to know firstly, if it matters which order they appear in, and why most instructions seems to include the function last?

```
add_action( $hook, 'foo', $priority, $accepted_args );
function foo() {
    // Function code
}
```

or

```
function foo() {
    // Function code
}
add_action( $hook, 'foo', $priority, $accepted_args );
```

Wouldn't it make more sense to use the latter as the function has already been read?

Comment: Given that both function declarations are anonymous (they have no name), this example doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: It's just an example to visually show the order. They would be named accordingly, and referenced in the add_action.

Comment: Whether it matters or not depends on what `add_action` does exactly… Generally: if it works, well, apparently it *doesn't* matter.

Answer (score 0):

The order doesn't matter.  The PHP interpreter uses a 2-pass approach. The functions are defined in the first pass, and your function is only run later when it's called by `do_action( $hook )`.

A little more about this here: [Does PHP interpret code in the same way that JavaScript does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286569/does-php-interpret-code-in-the-same-way-that-javascript-does)

Comment: This is only true for "flat" function declarations. Function declarations within a function or other conditional statement like an `if` can very well produce errors if you try to call them before they're defined.